# These scripts work on their own but when I try to put them in on script it fails

Tags: sudo, su

So I need these in one script. The first operation must be run as super user to run and for the proper permissions, the second operation must be run as the current logged in user. The script gets to line 12 before it outputs a syntax error. I think it's because the script is being run as sudo and inside it is trying to execute as another user but I am a novice so I'm not completely sure if that is the issue or not.

```
#!/bin/bash

hdiutil attach -nobrowse /var/tmp/dataloader/zuluintel.dmg
installer -package /Volumes/Azul\ Zulu\ JDK\ 11.56+19/Double-Click\ to\ Install\ Azul\ Zulu\ JDK\ 11.pkg -target /
hdiutil detach /Volumes/Azul\ Zulu\ JDK\ 11.56+19
cd /private/var/tmp/dataloader/dataloader_mac
loggedInUser=`/bin/ls -l /dev/console | /usr/bin/awk '{ print $3 }'`
sudo -u "$loggedInUser" -H  /bin/bash/ (echo ; sleep 5; echo "yes"; sleep 5; echo "yes"; sleep 5; echo "yes") | ./install.command
exit 0
```

Comment: There aren't 12 lines in your script! Also, what is the syntax error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is the error I get every time. This script is run as sudo since the .dmg needs admin privledges. But the install.command needs to be run as the logged in user since the install that it commands has to mirror the user permissions. The the install command prompts for input hence the echo's and sleeps. 



/private/var/tmp/dataloader/intel.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/private/var/tmp/dataloader/intel.sh: line 12: `su $loggedInUser /bin/bash/ (echo ; sleep 5; echo "yes"; sleep 5; echo "yes"; sleep 5; echo "yes") | ./install.command'

Comment: So figured out the syntax was because of the parenthasys. I replaced them with quotes but now I'm getting Can't open input file "echo; sleep 5; echo "yes"; sleep 5; echo "yes"; sleep 5; echo "yes"" | ./install.command